# g++, Xerces 3.1, "memcpy was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, g++, xerces, xerces-c

In my makefile on this project, I am specifying 3 location for the compiler to find #includes.

```
INCLUDES=-I. -I/home/kelly/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/src -I/home/kelly/Utilities_New
```

When I compile the following sample code with the command line found in the comment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>

using namespace std;

/*
g++ -I. -I/home/kelly/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/src -I/home/kelly/Utilities_New test.cpp
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "this works" << endl;
}

In file included from /home/kelly/Utilities_New/string.h:5:0,
             from /home/kelly/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/xercesc/framework/XMLBuffer.hpp:28,
             from /home/kelly/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp:26,
             from test.cpp:7:
/home/kelly/Utilities_New/defs.h:26:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Clearly the compiler has decided that when it processes the Xerces #includes and finds string.h in the Utilities_New directory, it has found what it needs and stops there.

This other string.h was written by another programmer and I am attempting to use his library.

I thought that the standard locations were searched first.  I'm a little lost here.  I may be missing something super obvious to you all.

Also, wasn't there some rule about #include files that had <> vs. "" around them and where the compiler was supposed to look?

Comment: You may be fighting a linker flag that says to use or not use standard libraries by default.  Give that a quick peek.

Comment: <> the search path - "" local path first

Answer (score 0):

1. The standard locations are searched last.
2. `#include "blah"` is identical to `#include <blah>` unless `blah` is found in the same directory as the file that tries to include it. (And unless you use the rare and gcc-specific `-iquote` option).

For more information see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).